# How can i save and load items in canvas format in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapcanvas

I've created a leaflet map and added draw control. I can draw lines, polygons, and markers but I need to add a canvas and draw my favorite drawing items like this :

[image]

I want to **save** these items and **load** them again on the map. How can I handle this?

Comment: Start with https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Leaflet.MapPaint

Comment: tnx alot - you save my time